# Why h2 database have data conversion error converting

Tags: java, spring, database, h2

I have problem with h2 database.

I try to into values to the database like this

```
INSERT INTO INGREDIENT(id,name,type) values ('FLTO','pszenna','WRAP');
```

But then i got this error

> Data conversion error converting "'WRAP' (INGREDIENT: ""TYPE"" INTEGER)"; SQL statement:

also when i do smth like down my query is working

```
INSERT INTO INGREDIENT(id,name,type) values ('FLTO','pszenna','3');
```

but in schema.sql file the type field is varchar so why this doesnt working

```
create table if not exists Ingredient (
  id varchar(4) not null,
  name varchar(40) not null,
  type varchar(10) not null
);
```

Comment: H2 believes your `type` column is an integer, and it complains that it can't convert `'WRAP'` to integer. The second example works beacause `'3'` can be converted to `3`.

Comment: Okey i know this but i create a field type like varchar not int so this should working

Comment: Verify that `create` and `insert` are applied to the same database; append `;IFEXISTS=TRUE`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bh2%5d%20IFEXISTS%20TRUE) to avoid creating spurious database files.

Comment: Try to drop and re-create the table. You may have an older schema still, and "create table if exists" ends up doing nothing.

Comment: @Spectra how did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The Type type field of Ingredient entity class should be annotated with @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)

```
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private final Type type;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your error with code (using Spring's JdbcTemplate) but it runs succesfully:

```
@Test
public void testH2() {
    JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource();
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:h2:file:/tmp/test123");
    JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    jdbc.update("drop table if exists ingredient");
    jdbc.update(
            "create table if not exists ingredient(" +
            " id varchar(4) not null," +
            " name varchar(40) not null," +
            " type varchar(10) not null)"); // if this is " type int)" I get the same error message
    jdbc.update("delete from ingredient");
    showTable(jdbc, "empty");
    jdbc.update("insert into ingredient(id,name,type) values ('FLTO','pszenna','3')");
    showTable(jdbc, "added FLTO");
    jdbc.update("insert into ingredient(id,name,type) values ('FLTW','pszennb','WRAP')");
    showTable(jdbc, "added FLTW");
}

void showTable(JdbcTemplate jdbc, String message) {
    System.out.println("=== " + message + " ===");
    jdbc.query("select id, name, type from ingredient order by id", rs -> {
        int n = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("id=" + rs.getString(1) + " name=" + rs.getString(2) + " type=" + rs.getString(3));
            n++;
        }
        System.out.println(n + " rows");
        return n;
    });
}
```

If I change the type of `type` to `int` I get the exact same error message as you.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, so i think the problem is smth with the database because when i want

> DROP TABLE Ingredient;

I got error table "Ingrdient" not found.

This is my application.properties file

```
# Enabling H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

# Custom H2 Console URL
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

Idk what i should to do

Comment: H2 in-memory databases are a little tricky because they disappear when you close the last connection.  If you change your url to something like `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:mydb` you might get better results.

Comment: Another way to get around it is to add `;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` to the jdbc url like this: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`